# blueimp jQuery-File-Upload filtering types and files size and send new parameters

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, file-upload, filtering

I'm using the jQuery plugin [jQuery-File-Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Basic-plugin) with this JS code:

```
  $('#file_upload_single').fileupload({
        dataType: 'json',
        acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|tif|png)$/i,
        maxFileSize: 20000000, // 20MB            
        done: function (e, data) {
            $.each(data.result, function (index, file) {
                var msg = file.name + " upload terminado.";
                $('<p/>').text(msg).appendTo($('#progressLog'));
            });
            $('#progressBar .bar').css('width','0%');
        },
        progressall: function (e, data) {
            var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
            $('#progressBar .bar').css('width',progress + '%');
        }
    });

    $('#file_upload_single').bind('fileuploadsubmit', function (e, data) {
        var inputs = data.context.find(':input');
        if (inputs.filter('[required][value=""]').first().focus().length) {
            alert("Por preencher");
            return false;
        }
        data.formData = inputs.serializeArray();
    });
```

And in HTML:

```
<form id="file_upload_single" action="UploadServlet" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input id="file_2" type="file" name="file_2" 
                   style="background: gainsboro;" size="70" />
            <p>
                <label for="file_2_title">Título:</label>
                <input id="file_2_title" name="file_2_title" type="text" required title="Título" size="30"/>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="file_2_desc">Descritivo</label>
                <input id="file_2_desc" name="file_2_desc" type="text" required title="Descritivo" size="60"/>
            </p>
        </form>
        <button id="formSubmit_single" class="myButton ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all bt_register" 
                type="button" name="formSubmit_single" value="Upload" title="Máx. 20MB cada, do tipo: gif, jpeg, jpg, tif ou png">Imagem única, com descritivo</button>
```

The files are uploaded correctly, if the bind method is commented, but none of the filters is done: acceptFileTypes and maxFileSize. In servlet, "String file_2_title = request.getParameter("file_2_title");" gives null.

If the bind method is not commented (like above), nothing runs! Firebug shows:

```
TypeError: data.context is undefined
var inputs = data.context.find(':input');
```

The bind method is like in [Submit Form Data](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/How-to-submit-additional-Form-Data). What's wrong?

Comment: Well... I used another [plugin](https://github.com/Valums-File-Uploader/file-uploader).

Answer (score 0):

I have used a different approach to solve the issue with the additional form data. I did it in the "add" callback.

```
add: function (e, data){
    data.formData = {customInfo: <custom information>};
    data.submit();
},
```

This works fine. But I was not able to make the filters work too.